# Get result from a website using post through web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Here is the link to the website from which I want to get my data
[Puplic Search of Trademarks](http://ipindiaonline.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/frmmain.aspx)

In order to do so, I need to fill a form but I want to fill that form using the Python `requests` library. I have written some code for this, take a look:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests,json

def returnJson(wordmark,page_class):
    url="http://ipindiaonline.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/frmmain.aspx"
    search_type='WM'
    postdata={'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLFilter':'0','ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLSearchType':search_type,'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TBWordmark':wordmark,'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TBClass':page_class}
    r=requests.post(url,data=postdata)
    return r

def scrapping(r):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())
    '''soup.find_all('p')'''

scrapping(returnJson('AIWA','2'))
```

But when I run this code, it returns the same HTML of the page in response, but I want the search results so that I can print it on my terminal.

Note:- I have inspected the post request it sends and based on that file I have made that postdata Dictionay.

[image: here is screenshot of file]

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post requires a few more values for it to work. These can be obtained by first requesting the page without a search (probably only needed once if you are doing multiple searches). For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests,json

def returnJson(wordmark, page_class):
    url = "http://ipindiaonline.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/frmmain.aspx"

    r_init = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r_init.text, 'html.parser')
    event_validation = soup.find("input", attrs={"name" : "__EVENTVALIDATION"})['value']
    view_state = soup.find("input", attrs={"name" : "__VIEWSTATE"})['value']

    search_type = 'WM'

    postdata = {
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLFilter' : '0',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLSearchType' : search_type,
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TBWordmark' : wordmark,
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TBClass' : page_class,
        '__EVENTVALIDATION' : event_validation,
        "__EVENTTARGET" : "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$BtnSearch",
        "__VIEWSTATE" : view_state,
    }

    r = requests.post(url, data=postdata)
    return r

def scrapping(r):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    print(soup.prettify())
    '''soup.find_all('p')'''

scrapping(returnJson('AIWA','2'))
```

Comment: thank you it worked. but now there is a  button "show details" on the web page. it fetches data through ajax call. I am unable to fetch that data can you help?

Comment: I was going to suggest you start a new question, but I see you have [scrape a page to get javascript link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050096/scrap-a-page-to-get-encoded-javascript-link)

Comment: I created that question but I didn't get a satisfactory answer, so can you help ?